# How to handle hibernate Deadlock? (c3p0)

Tags: hibernate, c3p0, database-deadlocks

When a DEADLOCK is recognized by hibernates DeadlockDetector (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector), and SQL ERROR 1205 (Lock wait timeout) repeatedly, all threads of c3p0 got stuck and the hole application freezes.
I'm not interested in solutions avoiding the deadlock itself, but in possibilities to react this programmatically.

In this case some other application produced a table lock on the database server.
After i killed the application (SIGKILL) and restarted it all was fine again.

```
APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
SQL Error: 1205, SQLState: 40001
Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

used versions:
c3p0 : 0.9.5.2
hibernate: 5.0.0.CR1
no spring involved at all.

full stack trace:

```
2019-04-12 15:04:27,102 [WARN ] Slf4jMLog$Slf4jMLogger$WarnLogger (C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2s35s8a24vskkqigquy5|31304f14]-AdminTaskTimer) - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@4d710599 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating
emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
2019-04-12 15:04:27,104 [WARN ] Slf4jMLog$Slf4jMLogger$WarnLogger (C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2s35s8a24vskkqigquy5|31304f14]-AdminTaskTimer) - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@4d710599 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete
Status:
Managed Threads: 3
Active Threads: 3
Active Tasks:
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@679ab26c
on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2s35s8a24vskkqigquy5|31304f14]-HelperThread-#2
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@c9f62bd
on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2s35s8a24vskkqigquy5|31304f14]-HelperThread-#0
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@6250fbb8
on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2s35s8a24vskkqigquy5|31304f14]-HelperThread-#1
Pending Tasks:
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@4cdc18cd
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@7ee7dae8
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@99ac503
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@6cf272b3
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@40c40590
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@34b7fa
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@5f59d822
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@20414e90

Pool thread stack traces:

Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2s35s8a24vskkqigquy5|31304f14]-HelperThread-#2,5,main]
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.realClose(PreparedStatement.java:2689)
com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.close(StatementImpl.java:534)
com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:53)
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:934)
com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)

Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2s35s8a24vskkqigquy5|31304f14]-HelperThread-#0,5,main]
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.realClose(PreparedStatement.java:2689)
com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.close(StatementImpl.java:534)
com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:53)
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:934)
com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)

Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2s35s8a24vskkqigquy5|31304f14]-HelperThread-#1,5,main]
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.realClose(PreparedStatement.java:2689)
com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.close(StatementImpl.java:534)
com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:53)
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:934)
com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)

    #tread 1
2019-04-12 15:04:28,795 [WARN ] SqlExceptionHelper (qtp1548271808-41) - SQL Error: 1205, SQLState: 40001
2019-04-12 15:04:28,797 [ERROR] SqlExceptionHelper (qtp1548271808-41) - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
    #tread 2
2019-04-12 15:05:18,799 [WARN ] SqlExceptionHelper (qtp1548271808-23) - SQL Error: 1205, SQLState: 40001
2019-04-12 15:05:18,800 [ERROR] SqlExceptionHelper (qtp1548271808-23) - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
    #tread 3
2019-04-12 15:05:18,799 [WARN ] SqlExceptionHelper (qtp1548271808-22) - SQL Error: 1205, SQLState: 40001
2019-04-12 15:05:18,801 [ERROR] SqlExceptionHelper (qtp1548271808-22) - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

Comment: The APPARENT DEADLOCK should print a dump of what tasks are blocked. That's helpful for debugging. Please add that if you can.

Comment: I've added the stack traces by editing the post

Answer (score 0):

From the `APPARENT DEADLOCK` data dump, it's clear that you are experiencing deadlocks due to attempts to close cached statements freezing. This is a known issue / fragility with respect to the interaction of c3p0 statement caching and some (especially Oracle and jTDS) JDBC drivers.

There are two ways to address the issue. The simplest one is to disable statement caching: make sure c3p0 config parameters [maxStatements](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#maxStatements) and [maxStatementsPerConnection](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#maxStatementsPerConnection) are both set to zero.

If you gain performance benefits that you wish to keep from statement caching, c3p0 has a [setting to work around this issue](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads). **TL; DR:** add the c3p0 config property `c3p0.statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads=1`